# iterate through directory with Assets.getText

Tags: javascript, meteor

In meteor I can read a file like this:

```
myjson = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("lib/myfile.json"))
```

Now i want to iterate through a folder, and read all the available json files. What would be the best way to do this without installing extra NPM packages.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped Hubert OGs code into a function with Meteor.bindEnvironment. I believe this is necessary because of fibre not available outside of the Meteor environement.
see https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/49CkbYeyKoa7MyH5R

Beware that external Node packages have different document root than Meteor.

```
var done, files;

var fs = Npm.require('fs');

files = fs.readdirSync("../../../../../server/collections/lib/", function(e, r) {});

done = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(files) {
  return _.each(files, function(filename) {
    var myjson;
    myjson = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("lib/" + filename));
    /* do Something */

  });
}, function(e) {
  throw e;
});

done(files);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but is certainly an easy one:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

fs.readdir('./assets/app/myFolder', function(e, r) {
    _.each(r, function(filename) {
        Assets.getText('myFolder/' + filename);
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I wrap this into meteor. As I understand I have to wrap  with Meteor.bindEnvironment from non meteor libraries. But I can't get it work. Error Message:
Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.

Comment: wrapped your code into Meteor.bindEnvironment. Thank you for the hint!